# Error while instantiating the java chaincode on Hyperledger fabric network

Tags: java, docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

Java chaincode install is successful and I can see the chaincode has been installed successfully.

I am getting error while instantiating the java chaincode on Hyperledger fabric network.

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: 1: ./build.sh: not found

Can I get some help?

Thanks

Comment: where you able to fix this issue?